# Rails: Why "has_many ..., :through => ..." association results in "NameError: uninitialized constant ..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through

To express that a group can have multiple users, and a user can belong to multiple groups, I set the following associations:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_groups
  has_many :users, :through => :users_groups
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :users_groups
end

class UsersGroups < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

However, when I type:

```
Group.find(1).users
```

I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Group::UsersGroup
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`class UsersGroups` should be `class UsersGroup`. ActiveRecord models are singular - the tables are plural.

Comment: Thanks! It just looks strange/wrong to me to have a model called `UsersGroup`. I don't want one of them to be plural and the other singular. Maybe I should rename the model to something like UserGroupPair, so that the table name will be `user_group_pairs`. What do you think ?

Comment: When you have a join model, the standard practice is to come up with a word that describes the association. For example, GroupMembership or something. Just to check though, are you sure you need a join model? You can get away with just a table if the join doesn't need logic.

Comment: Do you mean model name `GroupMembership` and table name `group_membership`, i.e. both singular ? I'm not sure I understood your second point regarding getting rid of the join table. Could you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: If you don't like inconsistency then call the join model UserGroup - that would be normal for a rails project.  You'd have to rename the table to user_groups too.

Comment: @Misha You can get rid of the model but keep the table. But if you need the model, call it `GroupMembership` and the table `group_memberships`.

Comment: @Misha [See this for a discussion of many-to-many relationships](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/1/15/basic-rails-association-cardinality).

Comment: @Skilldrick Thanks! Now I understand what you meant.

Comment: Hi Skilldrick, does the plurality of the model name also have to correspond to the name of the file? I.e. users_group.rb?

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord tries to singularize the name, but your class is actually named `UserGroups`. Rename it to `UserGroup`. The models are singular.

Answer (score 1):

i think change name of class UserGroups to UserGroup

Answer (score -1):

In addition, please note that the filename of the model must also be in the singular form. 
In this case, `app/models/user_group.rb`

Comment: Not always. In this particular case it's ok.