# has_many / :through rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, has-many-through

I've been back on rails after long period on other techno, and it appears i'm a bit rusty.

I've been trying to handle Project, Client and Contact and I'm a little confused by the results.

At first I had just one "contact_id" in my Project and everything was find, but I figured out I'd really love to have multiple contacts for one project.

So this is what i've been trying :

**Project model:**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: User, foreign_key: "owner_id"
  belongs_to :worker, class_name: User, foreign_key: "worker_id"
  #  belongs_to :contact, class_name: Contact, foreign_key: "contact_id"
  has_many :project_contacts
  has_many :contacts, :through => :project_contacts
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :feedbacks
  before_save :set_estimated_time
  #pleinty of utilities
end
```

**Contact model:**

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, class_name: Client, foreign_key: "client_id"
  has_manny :project_contacts
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_contacts
end
```

**ProjectContact model:**

```
class ProjectContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

I thought it was ok but here's what I get when I use Rails console:

> 2.2.3 :001 > project = Project.find(31)
>         Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  'projects'.* FROM 'projects' WHERE 'projects'.'id' = 31 LIMIT 1
>        => # 
>       2.2.3 :002 > project.contacts
>       NameError: uninitialized constant Project::ProjectContact

Edit :

**Contact migration**

```
class AddProjectContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :project_contacts do |pc|
      pc.belongs_to :project, index: true
      pc.belongs_to :contact, index: true
      pc.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this

Bye

Comment: Did you run the migration? (I know stupid question, but you never know). Also, what does projet.project_contacts return? This association has to work before you can run project.contacts. Also for this kind of associations, if you don't need to do something special in your ProjectContact model, you should rather use has_and_belongs_to_many: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: Yes I did run the migration (i also inserted 1 row manualy to have a record).

project.project_contacts return "undefined method"

Comment: Should I add a foreign_key like :
  add_foreign_key :projectcontacts, :projects, column: :project_id, on_delete: :nullify

for project and contact ?

Comment: No I don't think you have to do that... Hmm... Let me test your code :)

Comment: Thank you :-).
Really hard to get back on rails on its own =]

Comment: I always recommend reading this book: https://www.railstutorial.org/book - you can upgrade your skills for free ;)

Comment: Could you also add project-relative paths to model files?

Comment: Basically there are all in app/models folder.

Comment: Your code work for me... that is so strange. I found a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040022/rails-why-has-many-through-association-results-in-nameerror-un but you don't seem to have the same convention problem here as you did not put any "s" at the end of the model classname...

Comment: Ok "have you tried turning it off and on again" issue i guess.
I've seen this question alreaddy i was not sure of my spelling with class like ProjectContact, but i thought it was OK.
I'm running ruby 2.2.3 and rails 4.2.4 btw.

Comment: Your spelling is ok I think... I think I would rather have used something with more meaning like: "ProjectManager" or "ProjectParticipant" for the join model, as "Contact" is a little bit too generic... but the issue is not linked to the spelling I think... Maybe try with another model name for the join model? Also try to comment everything in your models except for the lines needed to set the association, just to have some "clean models" and let us know if it solves anything. :)

Comment: Thank you Kuglar, just changed the table / class name and it works perfectly. \o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, here's how I'd expect it to look:

```
#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :project_contacts
   has_many :contacts, through: :project_contacts
end 

#app/models/project_contact.rb
class ProjectContact < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | project_id | contact_id | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :project
   belongs_to :contact
end

#app/models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :project_contacts
   has_many :projects, through: :project_contacts
end
```

This should give you the ability to call:

```
@project = Project.find params[:id]
@project.contacts #-> shows all contacts
```

Comment: Ok i wasn't sure wheter to pluralize projects or not on table name. Thank for update :-)

Comment: The table names are plurals, the models are singular!

Comment: Yes, i know, i was just not sure about the "subword". I guess it was logical to expect plural on this table.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `class Contact`: `has_many` and not `has_manny`.

Comment: Ok so I guess if you have a nice IDE to advise, that would be great (but it doesn't resolve my pb though)

Comment: Can you post your migration, please ?

Comment: @gaetan try the IDE called RubyMine ;)

Comment: When you type in the console `ProjectContact.all`, what do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i just changed the class name to "participant" to try and everything is fine. :-|

Comment: According to rails conventions the original table should have been projects_contacts (this is what is expected by a has_and_belongs_to_many association). But as you used the "through" association with a properly configured table name... it's weird it didn't work in the first place. As I said I tested it with those exact names and it worked for me... really really strange it did not work for you.

Comment: Can you post your new models?

Comment: The key is `Project::ProjectContact`